# jakarta.el library is flagged for security vulnaribility in NexusIQ [Quarkus]

Tags: security, glassfish, quarkus, nexus-iq

We use `quarkus-hibernate-validator` which pulls in `jakarta.el`. But recently all versions of `jakarta.el` is flagged by NexusIQ for a severe vulnaribility.

[https://securitylab.github.com/advisories/GHSL-2020-021-jakarta-el/][1]

Details as follows:

VULNERABILITY ISSUE
sonatype-2020-1438
ISSUE
sonatype-2020-1438
SEVERITY
Sonatype CVSS 3:7.5
CVE CVSS 2.0:0.0
WEAKNESS
Sonatype CWE:20
SOURCE
Sonatype Data Research
CATEGORIES
Data
EXPLANATION
The jakarta.el package contains an Improper Input Validation vulnerability. The LiteralExpression method in the ELParser class fails to properly identify literal expressions. Consequently, invalid expressions are evaluated as if they were valid. A remote attacker can exploit this vulnerability by crafting an EL expression containing a $ or # symbol followed by a backslash, /, and the payload. This will bypass current validations and cause the parser to evaluate the expression potentially allowing Remote Code Execution.

DETECTION
The application is vulnerable by using this component.

RECOMMENDATION
There is no non-vulnerable upgrade path for this component/package. We recommend investigating alternative components or a potential mitigating control.

ROOT CAUSE
jakarta.el-3.0.3.jbossorg-2.jarcom/sun/el/parser/ELParser.class( , )
ADVISORIES
Third Party:https://securitylab.github.com/advisories/GHSL-2020-021-jakarta-el/
CVSS DETAILS
Sonatype CVSS 3:7.5

Does Quarkus team have any recommendations on remediating this?

Answer (score 0):

You already have version 4.0.0 try to update the pom I put it in the tag properties <glassfish.el.version>4.0.0</glassfish.el.version> or declare all the dependency.

The link solution asks you to create an interceptor to get the request parameters of type GET,DELETE,UPDATE. For request of type POST get the json of the body

```
public String replaceElDelimiter(final String value) {
   if (value != null) {
       return value.replaceAll("\\$+\\{", "{");
   }
   return null;
}
```

after removing ${ add to the values ​​in the parameters or in the body you are using